# How to figure out key map redefined in vim plugin?

Tags: vim

I installed many plugins by vundle.
I found there maybe multiple plugins use the same hotkey.
Is there smart way to figure out which plugin contains such hotkey?

There are some tutorial about [key map](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29). But I still haven't any idea.

Comment: Yes. Almost every plugin comes with, at least, a short description/README and/or, at best, a thorough documentation. The author spent some non-negligible time writing and formatting all that, read it. Preferably *before* installing. Oh, and you don't *need* most of those plugins anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### A warning

Don't just install *many plugins*; you'll end up with a complex, slow, and indecipherable mess over time. Especially with plugin managers like Vundle, it's very easy to check out plugins. That benefit can turn bad if you forget to remove plugins that don't turn out to be useful for you.

#### How to check

In general, the plugin should advertise its features and defaults mappings (and hopefully provides configuration to change those!)

If you indeed have overlapping mappings, you should check:

1. The plugin's documentation.
2. The plugin's source code; look for `:*[nore]map` commands in the `plugin/pluginname.vim` script.
3. The actual existing mappings; the `:map` command lists those. You can restrict the command by modes (e.g. `:imap` for *insert mode* mappings) and starting keys (e.g. `:map <Leader>` lists all mappings that begin with the (configurable) *Leader* key).

#### How to change mappings

The canonical way to change plugin mappings is by defining your own mapping to `<Plug>...` targets that the plugin provides, e.g. `:nmap <F1> <Plug>PluginNameMapping`, in your `~/.vimrc`. Some plugins also use global variables; refrain from modifying the plugin script itself; rather, complain to its author!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is.

Use `:verbose map <YOURKEY>`. It will show you which file was the latest to modify this mapping.

Comment: Great tip about `:verbose`

Answer (score 1):

You can always try reading the plugins documentation or source... Till then:

```
:map <YOURKEY><CR>
```

will show what was `<YOURKEY>` mapped to (in normal mode, so you can try it with `:cmap`, `:vmap`, etc.). Sometimes it helps if it's mapped to a function which relates to the plugins' name.

And you can issue a single (c|v...) `:map` to dump the mapping table.

But assuming you might want to know about mapping which used in two (or more plugins), there is no easy way for that. Again, look at the plugins' documentation and/or source code.